# Custom global keybindings in cinnamon via gsettings

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am trying to setup some keyboard shortcuts for cinnamon:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list \
    "['custom0', \
    'custom1', \
    'custom2', \
    'custom3', \
    'custom4']"

## browser
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "browser"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh chromium-browser"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>b']"

## file manager
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name "fileManager"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh nemo"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding "<Primary><Shift><Alt>f"
## terminal
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ name "terminal"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gnome-terminal"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding "<Primary><Shift><Alt>t"
## gmrun
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ name "runDialog"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gmrun"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/ binding "<Primary><Shift><Alt>g"
```

But this doesn't have any effect. I am using cinnamon 2.4.5 on ubuntu 14.04.

I know this can be done through system preferences dialog, but I want to do it on the commandline (better choice for automation).

Answer (score 7):

I got this working under Ubuntu 14.10 onwards. This is the command that will create a custom key binding "slot"

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/']"
```

You then set the name, command and binding values

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "shutter"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "shutter -s"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "Print"

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name "shutter"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command "shutter -f"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding "<Ctrl>Print"
```

If I compare this to your question for cinnamon, I'm guessing the problem is likely that you have to fully qualify each item you're adding with the full path, like so:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list \
"['/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom0', \
  '/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom1', \
  '/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom2', \
  '/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom3', \
  '/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom4']"
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (Cinnamon 3.2.7 on Debian 9.4):

```
   gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list \
        "['custom0', \
        'custom1', \
        'custom2', \
        'custom3', \
        'custom4']"


## browser
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "browser"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh chromium-browser"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>b']"

## file manager
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ name "fileManager"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh nemo"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/ binding "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>f']"
## terminal
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom2/ name "terminal"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom2/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gnome-terminal"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom2/ binding "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>t']"
## gmrun
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom3/ name "runDialog"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom3/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gmrun"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom3/ binding "['<Primary><Shift><Alt>g']"
```

Verify your custom keybindings are set by running the following command:

```
dconf dump /org/cinnamon/
```

The new binding can also be seen in the settings GUI

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that setting shortcuts (/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings in my case) with 'gsettings' does not have a (direct) effect. Only if I make some (even unrelated) changes in the GUI, the shortcuts are actually refreshed.

I've written a Python program (based on the code of the cinnamon GUI) that toggles the shortcut key a script (between F21 and Multi_key) and has a direct effect. I guess altering it to your specific use case shouldn't be too hard.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess
from gi.repository import Notify
from gi.repository import Gio, Gdk

CUSTOM_KEYS_PARENT_SCHEMA = "org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings"
CUSTOM_KEYS_BASENAME = "/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings"
CUSTOM_KEYS_SCHEMA = "org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding"

curr_shortcut = subprocess.check_output(['gsettings','get', 'org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/', 'binding'])

custom_num=0

def remove_custom():
    keybinding_path='custom0'
    custom_path = CUSTOM_KEYS_BASENAME + "/" + keybinding_path + "/"
    custom_schema = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(CUSTOM_KEYS_SCHEMA, custom_path)
    custom_schema.delay()
    custom_schema.reset("name")
    custom_schema.reset("command")
    custom_schema.reset("binding")
    custom_schema.apply()
    Gio.Settings.sync()

    parent_settings = Gio.Settings(CUSTOM_KEYS_PARENT_SCHEMA)
    array = parent_settings.get_strv("custom-list")

    existing = False
    for entry in array:
        if keybinding_path == entry:
            existing = True
            break
    if existing:
        array.remove(keybinding_path)
        parent_settings.set_strv("custom-list", array)

def add_custom(key):
    parent = Gio.Settings.new(CUSTOM_KEYS_PARENT_SCHEMA)
    array = parent.get_strv("custom-list")

    new_str = "custom" + str(custom_num)
    array.append(new_str)
    parent.set_strv("custom-list", array)
    new_path = CUSTOM_KEYS_BASENAME + "/custom" + str(custom_num) + "/"
    new_schema = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(CUSTOM_KEYS_SCHEMA, new_path)
    new_schema.delay()
    new_schema.set_string("name", 'command_name')
    new_schema.set_string("command",'/path/to/script')
    new_schema.set_strv("binding",[key])
    new_schema.apply()
    Gio.Settings.sync()


if 'Multi_key' in curr_shortcut:
    remove_custom()
    add_custom('F21')
    Notify.init ("Shortcut disabled")
    SC_ON=Notify.Notification.new ("Shortcut","Shortcut disabled","dialog-information")
    SC_ON.set_urgency(0)
    SC_ON.show()
else:
    remove_custom()
    add_custom('Multi_key')
    Notify.init ("Shortcut enabled")
    SC_OFF=Notify.Notification.new ("Shortcut","Shortcut enabled","dialog-information")
    SC_OFF.set_urgency(0)
    SC_OFF.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have many shortcuts it's useful to put everything inside a loop like in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

##############################################################################
###                            CONFIGURATIONS
##############################################################################
name0="browser"
command0="/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh chromium-browser"
binding0="['<Primary><Shift><Alt>b']"

name1="fileManager"
command1="/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh nemo"
binding1="['<Primary><Shift><Alt>f']"

name2="terminal"
command2="/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gnome-terminal"
binding2="['<Primary><Shift><Alt>t']"

name3="runDialog"
command3="/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh gmrun"
binding3="['<Primary><Shift><Alt>g']"

gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list \
        "['custom0', \
        'custom1', \
        'custom2', \
        'custom3']"
##############################################################################

let x=0
name=$(echo "name$x")
command_a=$(echo "command$x")
binding=$(echo "binding$x")
while [ "${!name}" ] ; do
   gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom$x/ name "${!name}"
   gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom$x/ command "${!command_a}"
   gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding:/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom$x/ binding "${!binding}"
   x=$[$x+1]
   name=$(echo "name$x")
   command_a=$(echo "command$x")
   binding=$(echo "binding$x")
done
```

That makes organizing my shortcuts a lot easier. Basically, you just need to copy and paste a new block of `namex`, `commandx` and `bindingx` (**with x being the next shortcut number**) when you want to insert new shortcuts. For example:

```
namex="my command"
commandx="path/to/script"
bindingx="['<key><key><key>letter']"
```

Also, insert a new `customx` (**again with x being the next corresponding number**) on this part of the script:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list \
        "['custom0', \
        'custom1', \
        'custom2', \
        'custom3', \
        'customx']"
```

After executing the script it may be needed to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , type `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to start using your new shortcuts... It's not necessary to change anything outside the `CONFIGURATIONS` separation on the script...

Answer (score 0):

The one line that did it for Cinnamon 20.2 :

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme 'Emacs'
```