# Custom keybindings For Linux Mint 20 via gsettings

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, dconf, gsettings

The solution given in [Custom global keybindings in cinnamon via gsettings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174683/custom-global-keybindings-in-cinnamon-via-gsettings) is not working in Linux Mint 20.

I monitored the changes using `dconf watch /` and the following changes were made while creating the shortcut using GUI:

```
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list
  ['custom0']

/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding
  @as []

/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/command
  'screen -d -m "/home/blueray/src/Translate/screen_ts.sh"'
  
/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name
  'capture2text'

/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding
  ['<Super>q']
```

To set the first line I used:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings custom-list "['custom0']"
```

But when it comes to the second line it throws error:

```
% gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybindings.custom0 binding "@as []" 
No such schema “org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybindings.custom0”
```

How can I set custom shortcut in Linux Mint 20 using gsettings (not GUI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following lines as an example

```
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list "['custom0']"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/command "'tmux new-session -d "/home/blueray/src/Translate/screen_ts.sh"'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/name "'capture2text'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/binding "['<Super>q']"

# xkill keybinding for ctrl + escape
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list "['custom0', 'custom1']"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/command "'xkill'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/name "'xkill'"
dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom1/binding "['<Primary>Escape']"
```

Comment: `dconf write` woks to populate database. But keybindings do not start to work right away, I went to GUI keyboard and pressed  "update" for each - then they started to work. By try-and-error I've found a way to make them work: at the end again `dconf write /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-list "['__dummy__', 'custom0', 'custom1', 'custom2']"` with different order of items (were `"['custom0', 'custom1', 'custom2', '__dummy__']"`).